# Como le hago para almacenar datos sin que se repita, y como agregar datos en un formulario.

Tags: php, html

buen día! para todos estoy haciendo un proyecto, donde voy a registrar a algunas personas para darles cierto apoyo me pidieron que usara la CURP para que el usuario sea único y no pueda volver a pedir el ni el ni nadie de la familia de el. por que el apoyo es uno por familia, el problema que tengo, que tomar los datos de toda la familia pero si son familias grandes como le haría para guardar sus datos, de toda la familia. en la base de datos.

Comment: que haz intentado hasta el momento? por ejemplo como haz planteado la estructura de la BD?

Comment: para el escenario que mencionas, se me hace mas simple que tanto los datos de apellidos sea UNIQUE asi como el CURP ya que mencionas que solo un integrante de la familia puede recibir un apoyo, entonces mas que checar por medio de la CURP si alguien de la familia ya esta validas que solo alguien con GONZALEZ PEREZ ya se ingreso

Comment: ok muchas gracias, eso ya me quedo claro, pero ahora no se si me pudieras ayudar en este caso mira en el formulario de la encuesta, seria a un integrante de familia, pero habría una pregunta que se le haría, cuantas personas viven en su casa, a la hora de seleccionar el numero, yo quiero que se habrá los formularios que se necesiten por ejemplo si dice cuatro seria 4 formularios mas solo con nombre y apellido, para cada uno, ya lo tengo pero para guardarlos en la base de datos.

Comment: continuando con la pregunta anterior para que quede mas clara, el problema que la tabla de personas con apoyo pues seria con los datos de el lo que es Nombre. apellido. CURP, teléfono, domicilio lo básico. eso no es difícil, el hincapié es en la pregunta de cuantas personas viven en su casa. cuando sean muchas, como hago para que se agreguen en la base de datos. los formularios en HTML si me sirven y si se muestran así como te digo, pero ahria otra tabla para esa pregunta.